# Retrieving parent values from a JSONPath expression

Tags: json, parsing, jsonpath

I need to extract some values from a JSON like this ...

```
{
    "array": [{
        "name": "aaaa",
        "alt_name": "alt_aaa",
        "data": "2015-03-17",
        "subArraycore": [{
            "codname": "codname_xxx",
            "version": "3.0.0"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "bbb",
        "alt_name": "alt_bbb",
        "data": "2015-05-17",
        "subArraycore": [{
            "codname": "codname_xxx",
            "version": "3.1.0"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "ccc",
        "alt_name": "alt_ccc",
        "data": "2015-10-17",
        "subArraycore": [{
            "codname": "codname_xxx",
            "version": "3.2.0"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "ddd",
        "alt_name": "alt_ddd",
        "data": "2015-05-17",
        "subArraycore": [{
            "codname": "codname_xxx",
            "version": "3.1.0"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "eee",
        "alt_name": "alt_eee",
        "data": "2015-10-17",
        "subArraycore": [{
            "codname": "codname_xxx",
            "version": "3.2.0"
        }]
    }]
}
```

... using JSONPath.

I need to extract all the "name" values when subArraycore.version = "3.1.0".

Using `$..subArraycore[?(@.version=="3.1.0")]` I obtain

```
[
    {
        "codname": "codname_xxx",
        "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    {
        "codname": "codname_xxx",
        "version": "3.1.0"
    }
]
```

that's right, but this is only a portion of the JSONPath expression I think I've to use to obtain `"name": "bbb"` and `"name": "ddd"` that are the name values I need. How modify this JSONPath expression to obtain them ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that JSONPath is a selection language only. You can *filter* the input, but you cannot create or modify anything. Selecting `bbb` and `ddd` will not be possible because they do not exist in your input. You will have to some sort of post-processing.

Comment: @Tomalak I've tried to modify my original question to make it clearer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
$.array[?(@.subArraycore[0].version === '3.1.0')].name
```

Select those `array` members where the JS expression `subArraycore[0].version === '3.1.0'` is true, and from there get the `name`.

Result:

```
[
  "bbb",
  "ddd"
]
```